# @web/dev-server and disallowed MIME type (“text/css”)

Tags: javascript, swiper.js, web-development-server

I've installed SwiperJS via npm and trying to import modules into my app.js like so

```
import Swiper from 'swiper/bundle';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
```

I'm also using [@web/dev0server](https://modern-web.dev/) package and its `--node-resolve` flag to resolve bare module imports for use in the browser. So it loads the js modules just fine. But it can't load the `swiper/css` files. I get this error in the console

> http://localhost:8001/node_modules/swiper/modules/pagination/pagination.min.css”
> was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/css”).

Here's mine package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "wds --node-resolve --watch --open"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "swiper": "^8.4.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@web/dev-server": "^0.1.34"
  }
```

I understand that I probably need to configure @web/dev-server somehow but I can't figure out how exactly. The documentation doesn't really cover it except for very basic config examples that are of no use in this case. Any ideas how can I get it to work?

Comment: It is really look likes this [bug](https://github.com/modernweb-dev/web/issues/1523)

Comment: have you resolved this issue?

Comment: @iPhoneJavaDev can't recall really. I think I just switched to Vite